# VBA MS-Word How to import only determinated styles from a template

Tags: vba, import, ms-word, styles

Does anybody know how to do it? I'm importing all of styles from a template, but I only want to impot 1 or 2. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.OrganizerCopy [path to source template], ActiveDocument.FullName, [style name 1], wdOrganizerObjectStyles

Application.OrganizerCopy [path to source template], ActiveDocument.FullName, [style name 2], wdOrganizerObjectStyles
```